# Use of amazon device messaging (push notification service) in both iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, amazon-device-messaging

Is it possible to use Amazon device messaging for both iOS and Android devices? What are the limitations available in this service? What about the support of this service? Will i get documentations and code samples while integrating them in both server and mobile side?

Answer (score 0):

ADM is supported on Fire phone, Fire TV, and Fire tablets, except for Kindle Fire (1st Generation). For ADM notifications to appear on Fire TV, you must implement the Fire TV Notifications.